# How to prevent the deadlock in the below situation?

Tags: mariadb

I have a table, which should hold rows for `OrderGroups`. Basically, when a client creates an `Order`, his `Order` should be put inside a group based on his client id, until an administrator can verify the order. The `OrderGroups` tables structure is the following:

```
OrderGroupId                | IsClosed | clientId
-------------------------------------------------
INT PRIMARY (AutoIncrement) | BOOLEAN  | INT
```

My code should work in the following way: when a client creates a new order, we should check if he already has a NOT cloesd order group. If he has, we should attach that order group to his order. If he has none, we should create a new order group for him, and attach his order to the newly created group.

In the past, no locking was used when fetching/creating the order group, which resulted in naturally, that some clients, when inserting multiple orders concurently, ended up with multiple open order groups. I've modified my order group fetching query, to the following:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM OrderGroups WHERE clientId = {id} AND IsClosed = 0 FOR UPDATE;
// if no order groups are returned, insert a new group and use that one
// if an order group is returned, use the returned order group
END TRANSACTION;
```

This prevents the appeareance of multiple OrderGroups, but it sometimes results in a deadlock. I presume that the reason for this, is how `MariaDB` is locking the rows, when they are not present. Basically, if a result would be returned by the query in question, all subsequent calls requesting the same row, should wait, until the transaction that was first requesting it for update, commits or rolls back. But this is not the case, if a non-existent row gets locked this way. The insersions are still prevented (that is why I am getting the deadlock), but the select queries are processed.

Basically, this is what happens:

```
C1 -> BEGIN TRANSACTION;
C1 -> SELECT OrderGroups WHERE clientId = 1 AND IsClosed = 0 FOR UPDATE; // returns no rows
C2 -> BEGIN TRANSACTION;
C2 -> SELECT OrderGroups WHERE clientId = 1 AND IsClosed = 0 FOR UPDATE; // returns no rows, instead of waiting for C1 to commit or rollback the transaction
C1 -> INSERT INTO OrderGroups SET clientId = 1, IsClosed = 0; // holds, because C2 has a for update lock on the row? being inserted
C2 -> INSERT INTO OrderGroups SET clientId = 1, IsClosed = 0; // holds, because C1 has a for update lock on the row
MARIADB -> randomly kills C1 or C2 because of the deadlock, while the other may finish
```

How could I avoid this deadlock situation, and still maintain the single open group policy for the OrderGroups table?

Comment: a trigger would prevent adding new order_groups much more efficient

Comment: could you elaborate please?

Comment: lock are always tricky. so write an INSERT Trigger that check if the insert order_group already exists and then inserts when not or make something else, so you don't need to lock anything, the rest makes the system

Comment: Looks as if you are affected by Gap Locks, as e.g. described by this article:

https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/03/27/innodbs-gap-locks/

Suggested solutions in there:

* Change the ISOLATION level to READ COMMITTED
* or set innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog = 1

Comment: wouldn't lowering the isolation level to `READ COMMITTED`, result in the possiblity, that two OrderGroups get inserted, breaking our inner policy of how OrderGroups should be created? basically, if I understand the article correctly, with the proposed solution, I would only achieve that the rows would not be locked, but what I want is, to somehow get an exclusive lock (which prevents both reading and writing), for all now and future rows in the table, that matches the clientId

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, I managed to resolve this in a kind of hackish way, by inserting a new, unique column inside the table.

I've inserted the `UniqId (VARCHAR(20))` column as a unique in the database. When I am trying to fetch or create a new row in the table, instead of selecting and then inserting if nothing is found, I just simply make an `INSERT IGNORE INTO ...` using `c{clientId}` for the `UniqId` column. Whenever the order group is closed, I update the `UniqId` column to the primary key of the table.

This way, when performing the `INSERT IGNORE`, if the row already exists, it gets locked, and I will be able to select it inside the next SELECT statement, and if the row does not exist yet, it gets inserted and also gets locked, and I am able to select it in the next select statement.

This is a rather hacky way to solve my exact situation, but I am still open to suggestions for the possibility, to somehow get an exclusive lock for a row in the table, that does not exist yet.